# D3.js Gauge Chart Indicators And Labels Positioning

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js, svg

I am new to **[D3.js | Data-Driven Documents](https://d3js.org/)** charts and I am working with a **Gauge Chart** style using this. For this purpose, I searched over the internet and found the below simple code with some tweaks from my side and it is working well as shown in the below screenshot.

[image]

And the code for this is shared below.

### D3.js Gauge Chart Basic Code:

```js
/*---------------------
// D3.js Gauge Chart //
---------------------*/
// Data which need to be fetched
var name = "Server Response";
var value = 75;    // My Desired Value To Show
var gaugeMaxValue = 100;

// Data of calculation
var percentValue = value / gaugeMaxValue;
var needleClient;
(function () {
 var barWidth, chart, chartInset, degToRad, repaintGauge, height, margin, numSections, padRad, percToDeg, percToRad, percent, radius, sectionIndx, svg, totalPercent, width, recalcPointerPos;

 percent = percentValue;

 numSections = 1;
 sectionPerc = 1 / numSections / 2;
 padRad = 0.025;
 chartInset = 10;

 // Orientation of Gauge:
 totalPercent = .75;

 el = d3.select('.chart-gauge');

 margin = {
  top: 20,
  right: 20,
  bottom: 20,
  left: 20
 };

 width = el[0][0].offsetWidth - margin.left - margin.right;
 height = width;
 radius = Math.min(width, height) / 2;
 barWidth = 40 * width / 300;

 // Utility methods 
 percToDeg = function (perc) {
  return perc * 360;
 };

 percToRad = function (perc) {
  return degToRad(percToDeg(perc));
 };

 degToRad = function (deg) {
  return deg * Math.PI / 180;
 };

 // Create SVG element
 svg = el.append('svg').attr('width', width + margin.left + margin.right).attr('height', height / 1.5 + margin.top + margin.bottom);  // height/1.5 To Remove Extra Bottom Space

 // Add layer for the panel
 chart = svg.append('g').attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 2) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")");

 chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-first");
 chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-second");
 chart.append('path').attr('class', "arc chart-third");

 arc3 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)
 arc2 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)
 arc1 = d3.svg.arc().outerRadius(radius - chartInset).innerRadius(radius - chartInset - barWidth)

 repaintGauge = function () {
  perc = 0.5;
  var next_start = totalPercent;
  arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
  arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 3);
  next_start += perc / 3;

  arc1.startAngle(arcStartRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

  arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
  arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 3);
  next_start += perc / 3;

  arc2.startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

  arcStartRad = percToRad(next_start);
  arcEndRad = arcStartRad + percToRad(perc / 3);

  arc3.startAngle(arcStartRad + padRad).endAngle(arcEndRad);

  chart.select(".chart-first").attr('d', arc1);
  chart.select(".chart-second").attr('d', arc2);
  chart.select(".chart-third").attr('d', arc3);
 } 
 
 var Needle = (function () {

  //Helper function that returns the `d` value for moving the needle
  var recalcPointerPos = function (perc) {
   var centerX, centerY, leftX, leftY, rightX, rightY, thetaRad, topX, topY;
   thetaRad = percToRad(perc / 2);
   centerX = 0;
   centerY = 0;
   topX = centerX - this.len * Math.cos(thetaRad);
   topY = centerY - this.len * Math.sin(thetaRad);
   leftX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
   leftY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad - Math.PI / 2);
   rightX = centerX - this.radius * Math.cos(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
   rightY = centerY - this.radius * Math.sin(thetaRad + Math.PI / 2);
   return "M " + leftX + " " + leftY + " L " + topX + " " + topY + " L " + rightX + " " + rightY;
  };

  function Needle(el) {
   this.el = el;
   this.len = width / 2.5;
   this.radius = this.len / 8;
  }

  Needle.prototype.render = function () {
   this.el.append('circle').attr('class', 'needle-center').attr('cx', 0).attr('cy', 0).attr('r', this.radius);
   return this.el.append('path').attr('class', 'needle').attr('id', 'client-needle').attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(this, 0));
  };

  Needle.prototype.moveTo = function (perc) {
   var self,
    oldValue = this.perc || 0;
   this.perc = perc;
   self = this;

   // Reset pointer position
   this.el.transition().delay(100).ease('quad').duration(200).select('.needle').tween('reset-progress', function () {
    return function (percentOfPercent) {
     var progress = (1 - percentOfPercent) * oldValue;
     repaintGauge(progress);
     return d3.select(this).attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
    };
   });

   this.el.transition().delay(300).ease('bounce').duration(1500).select('.needle').tween('progress', function () {
    return function (percentOfPercent) {
     var progress = percentOfPercent * perc;

     repaintGauge(progress);
     return d3.select(this).attr('d', recalcPointerPos.call(self, progress));
    };
   });

  };

  return Needle;

 })();

 var dataset = [{
  metric: name,
  value: value
 }]

 var texts = svg.selectAll("text")
  .data(dataset)
  .enter();

 texts.append("text")
  .text(function () {
   return dataset[0].metric;
  })
  .attr('id', "Name")
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 6) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 1.5) + ")")
  .attr("font-size", 25)
  .style("fill", "#000000");


 var trX = 180 - 210 * Math.cos(percToRad(percent / 2));
 var trY = 195 - 210 * Math.sin(percToRad(percent / 2));
 // (180, 195) are the coordinates of the center of the gauge.

 displayValue = function () {
  texts.append("text")
   .text(function () {
    return dataset[0].value;
   })
   .attr('id', "Value")
   .attr('transform', "translate(" + trX + ", " + trY + ")")
   .attr("font-size", 18)
   .style("fill", '#000000');
 }

 texts.append("text")
  .text(function () {
   return 0;
  })
  .attr('id', 'scale0')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 100) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")")
  .attr("font-size", 15)
  .style("fill", "#000000");

 texts.append("text")
  .text(function () {
   return gaugeMaxValue / 2;
  })
  .attr('id', 'scale10')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 2.15) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 30) + ")")
  .attr("font-size", 15)
  .style("fill", "#000000");


 texts.append("text")
  .text(function () {
   return gaugeMaxValue;
  })
  .attr('id', 'scale20')
  .attr('transform', "translate(" + ((width + margin.left) / 1.03) + ", " + ((height + margin.top) / 2) + ")")
  .attr("font-size", 15)
  .style("fill", "#000000");

 needle = new Needle(chart);
 needle.render();
 needle.moveTo(percent);

 setTimeout(displayValue, 1350);

})();
```

```css
.chart-gauge {}
.chart-first {fill:#458B00}
.chart-second {fill:#e6e600}
.chart-third {fill:#e92213}
.needle,.needle-center {fill:#464A4F}
```

```html
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://d3js.org/d3.v3.min.js"></script>
<div class="chart-gauge"></div>
```

*Alternate:* **[JS Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/t019mo73/)** (https://jsfiddle.net/t019mo73/)

Now I have some problems here that I want to fix. *First* of all I want to fix the positioning of labels and then *Second* I want to add more indicators and *Third* one is that I want to split Green, Yellow, Red section as per my desires like 15%, 60%, 25% as an example. What I want is also demonstrated in the below screenshot.

[image]

**So is this anything possible to fix it in my upper mentioned code?**

Comment: Have there been any updates to this issue? I'm working on a very similar use case.